# Pointcloud data to mesh conversion

Tags: ros-melodic, mesh, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to create a mesh out of a pointcloud which I keep in a list, let's say. Is this really possible? If so, does anyone know a way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322908/pointcloud-data-to-mesh-conversion/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can be done with functionality available in PCL, here's a example of using it that: [cloud_to_mesh_node](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_perception/blob/master/vigir_point_cloud_proc/src/cloud_to_mesh_node.cpp), [cloud_to_mesh_ros.h](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_perception/blob/master/vigir_point_cloud_proc/include/vigir_point_cloud_proc/cloud_to_mesh_ros.h). This node converts a point cloud it receives on the `~/cloud` topic to a mesh and publishes that as a Marker or Shape message.

Using PCL functionality like this might not be the most efficient method though. For real-time use you might want to look into using other tools like [voxblox](https://github.com/ethz-asl/voxblox). This builds a TSDF or ESDF representation from sensor data and can efficiently mesh it in real-time.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2019-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-05-28**:
Thanks! Voxblox looks impressive, I'll take a look into it!

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-04-27**:
@Jägermeister, have you tried Voxblox to create mesh file? I am also working on same problem. please share your solution if you have made it?